# how do I pass user profile data with extra context in class-based generic views?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, user-profile, django-context

I have model:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    begins_at = models.DateTimeField()
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

user profile:

```
class InstructorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    level = models.CharField()
```

and class-based generic views in urls.py:

```
url(r'^schedule/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(model=Schedule)),
```

How can I pass InstructorProfile level with extra context to my template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with the class-based views, it's a simple matter of accessing a user profile. If your user profile is defined in the settings file as the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE, then in the template you access it simply as `{{ schedule.instructor.get_profile }}`.